# Как убрать дубли страниц?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Привет всем!

Сейчас страница доступна и по такому адресу `site.loc/page/2` и по такому `site.loc/index.php?view=page&page_id=3`. Движок самописанный.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/(\d+)/?$ index.php?view=page&page_id=$1
```

Вопрос такой: как мне убрать дубликаты через .htaccess или php? Если кратко, то надо сделать редирект с `site.loc/index.php?view=page&page_id=3` на `site.loc/page/2`.

Comment: вроде бы rel=canonical. как раз для этого

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^index.php$
RewriteRule ^index.php?view=(.*)&page_id=(.*)$ http://site.loc/$1/$2 [L,R=301]
```

Как-то так, но тут вопрос как по мне должен быть как раз в СЕО части, так как тот момент что страница доступна по нескольких адресам не является проблемой, но вот то что поисковые системы их индексируют отдельно - уже проблема. Как написал комментатор выше rel=canonical решит проблему!

К примеру движок OpenCart очень сильно грешит тем что можно к странице обратиться по ЧПУ, по полному пути с категорией и постом через ГЕТ, и напрямую по ИД записи, и при этом канонический путь очень сложно правельно настроить.